# Is there any way to forward ALL invokes targeted to another object instead of the original one in SWIFT

Tags: swift, delegates, runtime

Let's take UIScrollView as the example, if I want to handle the content offset updates, or anything else in the UIScrollViewDelegate, I have to register the delegate for the scroll view. In my situation, there has been a delegate already, I just need to do something additionally instead of breaking it.

There's a STUPID way to do that, I have implemented all the methods in the protocol, no matter being used or not, and forwarded all of them to the original delegate. I don't think that will be a good idea at all. So I'm wondering if there's any better way to do that.

Thanks

Comment: so you need multiple delegates  ?

Comment: perhaps more that it, in the case the delegate is just for example. If I check the frame of the scroll view, i need the alias object response it.

Comment: So you need key value observation ?

Comment: maybe not, as there are lots of properties that I have to focus on, there will be lots of duplicated code about kvo  :(     and the most important is, in some cases, I don't know how many functions in the original instance